# Can't migrate 'Flask Migrate' in Heroku

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have worked a Flask application done in local. And then, I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku. The app might have been successfully in server now. But I'm having trouble getting `Flask Migrate` is not working.

```py
$ heroku run flask db init

  Creating directory /app/migrations ...  done
  Creating directory /app/migrations/versions ...  done
  Generating /app/migrations/script.py.mako ...  done
  Generating /app/migrations/env.py ...  done
  Generating /app/migrations/alembic.ini ...  done
  Generating /app/migrations/README ...  done
  Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/app/migrations/alembic.ini' before proceeding.
```

`flask db init` is success ...

But,

```py
$ heroku run flask db migrate

Error: Path doesn't exist: 'migrations'.  Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.
```

The app can't find `migrations` folder. I tried to run like this.

```py
$ heroku run cd app flask db migrate

bash: line 0: cd: too many arguments
```

I doubt one thing that `flask db` create `migrations` and `.db` file under app directory, not under flask app directory. So README seems to be a little strange.

```py
$ flask db init
$ flask db migrate
$ flask db upgrade
$ mv dev.db app/
$ mv migrations app/
```

```
app - requirements.txt
    - README.md
    - Procfile
    - .gitignore
    - app - __pycache__
          - static
          - __init__.py
```

Comment: can you rush bash on heroku and examine your directory structure. that should confirm if the files are there or not

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i solved the problem  step by step

- create a postgres database

```
    $heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app app_name
```

- then get the database url like so

```
    $ heroku config --app app_name
```

- set the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to the url and corrected it to be like so

```
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql+psycopg2://thedatabasestring"
```

- create the migration folder **locally** by typing the command

```
    flask db init
```

- then run the migrate command

```
   flask db migrate
```

- next commit your changes and push ***Note: if you added migrations to .gitignore file remove it***

```
   git push heroku master
```

- then run

```
   heroku run flask db upgrade
```

- thats it
- if you can successfully query database in flask shell then the tables were successfuly created